# Find part of a string and output the whole string

Tags: php, string, strpos

I would like to find part of a string and if `true` I want to ouput the whole of the string that it finds.

Below is an example:

```
$Towns = "Eccleston, Aberdeen, Glasgow";
$Find = "Eccle";

if(strstr($Find, $Towns)){
    echo outputWholeString($Find, $Towns); // Result: Eccleston.
}
```

If anyone can shed some light on how to do this as well, and bare in mind that it will not be static values; the `$Towns` and `$Find` variables will be dynamically assigned on my live script.

Comment: The syntax is `strstr($haystack, $needle)`, 
so you probably mean `strstr($Towns, $Find)` instead of `strstr($Find, $Towns)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `explode()` and `strpos()` as

```
$Towns = "Eccleston, Aberdeen, Glasgow";
$data=explode(",",$Towns);// 
$Find = "Eccle";
foreach ($data as $town)
if (strpos($town, $Find) !== false) {
    echo $town;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://3v4l.org/eoclX)

Comment: With `explode()`, the string is converted to an array and the array is searched item per item. The `preg_match()` solution does not convert to array but the search is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there...

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$Towns = "Eccleston, Aberdeen, Glasgow";
$Find = "Eccle";

if(stripos($Towns, $Find)) {
    echo $Towns;
}
```

The output is: `Eccleston, Aberdeen, Glasgow` which is what I would call "the whole string".

---

If however you only want to output that partly matched *part* of "the whole string", then take a look at that example:

```
<?php
$Towns = "Eccleston, Aberdeen, Glasgow";
$Find = "Eccle";

foreach (explode(',', $Towns) as $Town) {
    if(stripos($Town, $Find)) {
        echo trim($Town);
    }
}
```

The output of that obviously is: `Eccleston`...

Two general remarks:

1. the `strpos()` / `stripos()` functions are better suited here, since they return only a position instead of the whole matched string which is enough for the given purpose.
2. the usage of `stripos()` instead of `strpos()` performs a case insensitive search, which probably makes sense for the task...

Comment: I think he wants to output Eccleston not the whole string.

Comment: @Swolschblauw Not sure, but I added a version modified into that direction. Thanks for mentioning that view...

Comment: @Swolschblauw, thanks, I didn't grasp that at first.

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_match()`, it is possible to search for `Eccle` and return the `Eccleston` word.

I use the Pearl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) `'#\w*' . $Find . '\w*#'` in the code below and the [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e4026cbbd93deaf8fef0365a7bc6cf6eacc2014) code.

The `#` characters are PCRE delimiters. The pattern searched is inside these delimiters. Some people prefer `/` as delimiter.
The `\w` indicates *word* characters.
The `*` indicates 0 or more repetions of the previous character.
So, the `#\w*Eccle\w*#` PCRE searches for an string containing `Eccle` surrounded by one or more *word* characters (*letters*)

```
<?php
$Towns = "Eccleston, Aberdeen, Glasgow";
$Find = "Eccle";

if (preg_match('#\w*' . $Find . '\w*#', $Towns, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
?>
```

Running code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e4026cbbd93deaf8fef0365a7bc6cf6eacc2014

Note: `'#\w*' . $Find . '\w*#'` is the same as `"#\w*$Find\w*#"` (note the surrounding single or double quotes). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php?lq=1).

Comment: @arkascha I did not fully understand the question at first, the solution is adapted

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) to search for a string inside another one:

```
if( strpos($Towns, $Find) === false ) {
    echo $Towns;
}
```

Note that you have to use "===" to know if strpos() returned false or 0.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `preg_match` function:

```
$Towns = "Eccleston, Aberdeen, Glasgow";
$Find = "Eccle";

preg_match("/\b\w*?$Find\w*?\b/", $Towns, $match);
$result = (!empty($match))? $match[0] : "";

print_r($result);   // "Eccleston"
```

Comment: @PaulH, you are wrong. Check your test code for typos ... and read about variables interpolation

Comment: That PCRE seams overly complex to me, why not `"/\w*$Find\w*/"`

Comment: you forgot about ungreedy operators and word boundaries

Comment: Can you explain the `\b`? Isn't `\w*` automatically delimited by a word boundary?

Comment: of course, not. But we should consider that the searched word can be either at start of some word or at the end or at some other position

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will always have $Towns separated by ", " then you could do something like this

```
$Towns = "Eccleston, Aberdeen, Glasgow";
$Find = "Eccle";    
$TownsArray = explode(", ", $Towns);

    foreach($TownsArray as $Town)
    {
       if(stristr($Find, $Town))
       { 
          echo $Town; break;
       }
    }
```

The above code will output the Town once it finds the needle and exit the foreach loop. You could remove the "break;" to continue letting the script run to see if it finds more results.